# How can I install a fence on top of this wall?

Tags: fence

I'd like to install a fence (180cm x 90cm) above a small wall (shown in photos below). Initially I wanted to screw C-shaped metal clips like 20cm below the top edge of the wall then vertically along my house'wall (see last picture with squares). The purpose is to prevent neighbours to see, so the top edge of the fence doesn't need to be that high.

Downside: the right edge of the fence won't be maintained by anything and wind will likely make it move quite a lot.

But then, what to do in order to avoid this? Is there a better solution altogether?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Given that you've already got the vines or honeysuckle or whatever the climbing greenery is, I'd be tempted to just bolt a trellis to the inside of the wall and let the vines grow into it to complete the "fence".

Comment: Sounds good actually, but I need the fence installed ASAP..

Comment: They grow fast.  Thread a few vines through to get started.

Comment: What about the fact that the top edge of the wall is A-shaped rather than flat? Won't it make it hard to install anything on top of it?

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat destructive and costly alternative:

Use concrete anchors to fasten 4x4s to the lower portion of the wall.  Cut the 4x4s so they are the same height as the wall to the right in the pictures.  Then you can lay a trellis, slats, or whatever across the 4x4s using screws, bolts, etc.  This will likely ruin your lovely greenery and cost more than your c-clip idea, but this might be sturdy enough.

Can't tell from the pics, but I'm assuming the ground that meets the fence is composed of those concrete blocks?  If there is dirt right up against the fence, drive the 4x4s in the ground for more support.

Alternatively, hammer off the sloped top of the wall so it is flat, and fix cinder blocks as high as you like.  This might actually preserve your vines.

Comment: This is what I would do as well. I would just add that you should use a treated wood and make sure you stain / paint it to protect it so it can last.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you recommend to install 2 wooden pillars against the wall, one at the far left of the wall and the other on the right, from the ground to top edge of the wall (and fencing stuff on top of these). I would need to remove most of the plant stuff covering the wall in this case isn't it? Don't think my wife will approve the idea.

Comment: Like I said, destructive and potentially costly.  Maybe if you _carefully_ peel back the greenery to expose the wall, you could save some of it.  And yes, two "pillars" or beams will likely do it.  How wide is the space?  Looks like 4'-5'?   If it's 6 or more you may want three to keep the cross fencing from warping too much.  If you're worried, try your c-clip idea.  That doesn't seem like it would be too expensive, and you would save your vines.  If it breaks, then you know that won't work.